# How to select elements between two h tags using xpath and selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to scrape this [website](https://www.nuffic.nl/en/subjects/orange-knowledge-programme/calls-group-training-maximum-24-months-tmt-plus-orange)

but seeing its element I got confused about how to extract the data which is located between two h3 tags. an h3 tag element contains a country name. until the next h3 tag (having another country name) there are some posts containing deadline text and file links related to that deadline. in fact each of them is a business tender opportunity posted for that country.

[image]

**inspect element:**

[image]

**after getting the data this is how I store them into the database.**

[image]

please note that we can't predict what country name and spelling might be in the h3 element in the future but we never want to miss any opportunity posted newly on the website.

can anyone help me with the XPath or selenium solution. your help is much appreciated.
I tried to figure it out for the last hours but could not come up with any good idea. thank you in advance

Comment: how to select all h4 located between two h3 tag

Comment: Post your HTML Dom code instead of screenshot. How could we debug the xpath?

Comment: Hi @MohamedSulaimaanSheriff you are right, I have given the link instead if someone tries to check. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code to get required output

```
container = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[h3 and h4]')
headers = container.find_elements_by_xpath('./h3')

data = []

for index, _header in enumerate(headers):
    header = _header.text
    _deadlines = container.find_elements_by_xpath('./h3[position()={}]/following-sibling::h4[starts-with(., "Deadline") and not(preceding-sibling::h3[position()={}])]'.format(index + 1, index + 2))
    _data = []
    for _deadline in _deadlines:
        link = _deadline.find_element_by_xpath('./following-sibling::p[1]//a').get_attribute('href')
        _data.append({_deadline.text: link})
    data.append([header, _data])

for item in data:
    print(item)
```

Note: this allows to get **only first link for each deadline** (even if there are more than one link)

Comment: Thank you. but still if its possible to get all the links , please assist me with the solution.

Comment: @TalibDaryabi I was not able to find efficient approach for it. Probably need separate question for this issue

Answer (score 0):

To extract and print the texts e.g. *Sahel - Sécurité et Etat de Droit & Santé et Droits Sexuels et Reproductifs - OKP-SHL-20047 (210.78 kB) (in French)*, etc from all of the `<li class="Fruit">` using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.nuffic.nl/en/subjects/orange-knowledge-programme/calls-group-training-maximum-24-months-tmt-plus-orange")
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("h4 +p")])
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.nuffic.nl/en/subjects/orange-knowledge-programme/calls-group-training-maximum-24-months-tmt-plus-orange")
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h4//following::p[1]")])
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.nuffic.nl/en/subjects/orange-knowledge-programme/calls-group-training-maximum-24-months-tmt-plus-orange")
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h4 +p")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.nuffic.nl/en/subjects/orange-knowledge-programme/calls-group-training-maximum-24-months-tmt-plus-orange")
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//h4//following::p[1]")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['Sahel - Sécurité et Etat de Droit & Santé et Droits Sexuels et Reproductifs - OKP-SHL-20047 (210.78 kB) (in French)', 'Sahel - Santé et Droits Sexuels et Reproductifs - OKP-SHL-20048 (193.91 kB) (in French)', 'Sahel - Sécurité et Etat de Droit - OKP-SHL-20049 (209.17 kB) (in French)', 'Capacity strengthening for Resilience in the Sahel\u200c (365.57 kB)', 'Tunesia - Sécurité, Stabilité et Migration - OKP-TUN-40014 (209.87 kB) (in French)', 'Tunisia - Country Plan of Implementation - Orange Knowledge (423.8 kB)', 'Nigeria - Food and Nutrition Security - OKP-NIG-20050 (211.74 kB)', 'Sub-Sahara Africa - Health - OKP-SSA-50002 (214.27 kB)', 'Health Systems Strengthening through education and training – In Burkina Faso, Burundi, Ethiopia, Mali, Niger (301.71 kB)', 'Benin - Santé et Droits Sexuels et Reproductifs - OKP-BEN-20053 (189.51 kB) (in French)', 'Benin - Country Plan of Implementation - Orange Knowledge (in French)', 'Indonesia - Security and the Rule of Law - OKP-IDN-20055 (204.89 kB)', 'Indonesia - Food and Nutrition Security, Water - OKP-IDN-20056 (202.17 kB)', 'Indonesia - Country Plan of Implementation - Orange Knowledge (613.86 kB)', 'Horn of Africa – Food and Nutrition Security, Security and Rule of Law - OKP-EAR-20058 (236.34 kB)', 'Capacity strengthening for Resilience in the Horn of Africa (252.64 kB)\u200c', 'Thematic call SRHR - OKP-SRHR-40015 (235.72 kB)']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: thank you for always being there to help. but the solution only gets the title of links. it misses the deadline and href value of each one. can you help me with that as well. suppose [   [sahel-xxxxxx,26-Jan, www.axxxx.pdf]      [.....]  ]